# Need help joining three tables by unique numeric ID using a view in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, join, sql-view

I'm working on a data model and I plan to split the columns that are in one table now into multiple tables as the expected update frequency of the different columns is expected to be very different.
Still I'd like to have one single view that outputs the illustration of all tables being just one.

Basically I have a name as primary key, and I use a separate ID table `(ID, NAME)` where `ID` is a unique primary key to identify the corresponding rows.
I also have a creator table `(ID, NAME)` that maps lengthy names to an ID.
The main data is split in two tables where each has an `ID` column for correlating with the ID table.

To make a long story short, here is the table definition with a stupid example data set:

```sqlite
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE KEY_ID (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(32));
INSERT INTO KEY_ID VALUES(1,'Name');
CREATE TABLE CREATORS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(32));
INSERT INTO CREATORS VALUES(1,'Creator');
CREATE TABLE KEY_DATA (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL REFERENCES KEY_ID(ID), KEY_DATA VARCHAR(4096), CREATOR_ID INTEGER not NULL REFERENCES CREATORS(ID), CREATED DATETIME, MODIFIED DATETIME, LOCKED DATETIME);
INSERT INTO KEY_DATA VALUES(1,'K',1,0,0,0);
CREATE TABLE KEY_PROT (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL REFERENCES KEY_ID(ID), DK_DATA VARCHAR(128), KEK_DATA VARCHAR(128));
INSERT INTO KEY_PROT VALUES(1,'X','Y');
DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence;
INSERT INTO sqlite_sequence VALUES('KEY_ID',1);
CREATE VIEW V AS SELECT KEY_ID.NAME AS NAME, KEY_DATA, CREATORS.NAME AS CREATOR, CREATED, MODIFIED, LOCKED, KEY_PROT.DK_DATA AS DK_DATA, KEY_PROT.KEK_DATA AS KEK_DATA FROM KEY_ID, CREATORS, KEY_DATA, KEY_PROT JOIN ID ON KEY_ID.ID = KEY_DATA.ID JOIN ID ON KEY_PROT.ID = KEY_DATA.ID JOIN ID ON CREATORS.ID = KEY_DATA.ID;
COMMIT;
```

When querying the view I get his error essage:

```sqlite
sqlite> select * from V;
Parse error: no such table: main.ID
```

What confuses me is that my view does not contain any table named `main`.
Maybe the while question can be re-phrased as "*How to map a foreign key relationship in a SQLite view?*".

## Attempts to solve the Issue

After reading "SQLite INNER JOIN examples" in [SQLite INNER JOIN with Examples](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-inner-join/) I still wasn't successful, so I tried to get the desired result with a `SELECT` first, but even that failed:

```sqlite
sqlite> CREATE VIEW V AS SELECT KEY_ID.NAME AS NAME, KEY_DATA, CREATORS.NAME AS CREATOR, CREATED, MODIFIED, LOCKED, KEY_PROT.DK_DATA AS DK_DATA, KEY_PROT.KEK_DATA AS KEK_DATA FROM KEY_ID, CREATORS, KEY_DATA, KEY_PROT FROM KEY_ID INNER JOIN ID ON KEY_ID.ID = KEY_DATA.ID INNER JOIN ID ON KEY_PROT.ID = KEY_DATA.ID INNER JOIN ID ON CREATORS.ID = KEY_DATA.ID;
Parse error: near "FROM": syntax error
  EK_DATA FROM KEY_ID, CREATORS, KEY_DATA, KEY_PROT FROM KEY_ID INNER JOIN ID ON
                                      error here ---^
sqlite> SELECT KEY_ID.NAME AS NAME, KEY_DATA, CREATORS.NAME AS CREATOR, CREATED, MODIFIED, LOCKED, KEY_PROT.DK_DATA AS DK_DATA, KEY_PROT.KEK_DATA AS KEK_DATA FROM KEY_ID, CREATORS, KEY_DATA, KEY_PROT INNER JOIN KEY_ID ON KEY_ID.ID = KEY_DATA.ID INNER JOIN KEY_ID ON KEY_PROT.ID = KEY_DATA.ID INNER JOIN KEY_DATA ON CREATORS.ID = KEY_DATA.CREATOR_ID;
Parse error: ambiguous column name: KEY_ID.NAME
  SELECT KEY_ID.NAME AS NAME, KEY_DATA, CREATORS.NAME AS CREATOR, CREATED, MODIF
         ^--- error here
```

Comment: There seem to be problems with the website since yesterday; I tried to add the missing parts, but I get an error message in Edge: "An error occurred submitting the edit.", "jquery.min.js:4 
        
      
        
        
      
        
      
       
        
       POST https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76011992/edit-submit/2a905a19-fd57-42e4-90f6-a579a2915165 net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Comment: Restarting Edge seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: Take some time to read about the syntax of joins: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-join/

Comment: I'd wish sqlite-doc-3410100/syntax/join-operator.html would have refered to that.

Comment: Unfortunately the SQLite Tutorial cited (as most others too) only talk about joining *two* tables, and specifically not talking about views. What I can see so far is that I want an "INNER" JOIN staring at `KEY_ID` and joining `KEY_DATA` and `KEY_PROT`, and eventually joining the `CREATORS`. So actually that's four tables. What also confuses me is the role of the part between `JOIN` and `ON` (as in "INNER JOIN artists r ON r.ArtistId = l.ArtistId").

Comment: In a query you can treat views just like a table. At the bottom of the page of the tutorial there is a right arrow (UP NEXT SQLite Inner Join) with examples for joining more than 2 tables. You could also google it like: "sqlite multiple joins different tables" an you will get many results.

Comment: Using the site with Edge is no fun: "Tracking Prevention blocked a Ping request to https://region1.google-analytics.com/g/collect?v=2&tid=G-WCZ03SZFCQ&gtm=45je34c0&_p=1967893849&gcs=G100&cid=1666112165.1681464254&ul=de&sr=1536x864&uaa=x86&uab=64&uafvl=Microsoft%2520Edge%3B111.0.1661.43%7CNot..." Isn't there enough built-in tracking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the essential hint in answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/267839/272354, meaning that there are *parent tables* and *child tables*.
Basically the error messages from SQLite aren't very helpful, and the solution is to drop most `AS` phrases in `SELECT` and to start with a `FROM` and the *parent table* (`KEY_ID`).

So I'm "disassembling" the view as numbered list below:

1. `CREATE VIEW V` # the *view*
2. `SELECT KEY_ID.NAME, KEY_DATA, CREATORS.NAME AS CREATOR, CREATED, MODIFIED, LOCKED, KEY_PROT.DK_DATA, KEY_PROT.KEK_DATA` # the *fields*
3. `FROM KEY_ID` # the *parent table*
4. `INNER JOIN KEY_DATA USING (ID)` # first *child table*
5. `INNER JOIN KEY_PROT USING(ID)` # second *child table*
6. `JOIN CREATORS ON CREATORS.ID = KEY_DATA.CREATOR_ID;` # third *child table* using different names in the fields; it seems `INNER JOIN CREATORS ON CREATOR_ID` also works

Here is the execution plan:

```sqlite
sqlite> explain select * from V;
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     29    0                    0   Start at 29
1     OpenRead       1     2     0     2              0   root=2 iDb=0; KEY_ID
2     OpenRead       2     5     0     6              0   root=5 iDb=0; KEY_DATA
3     OpenRead       3     6     0     3              0   root=6 iDb=0; KEY_PROT
4     OpenRead       4     4     0     2              0   root=4 iDb=0; CREATORS
5     Rewind         1     28    0                    0
6       Rowid          1     1     0                    0   r[1]=KEY_ID.rowid
7       SeekRowid      2     27    1                    0   intkey=r[1]
8       Rowid          1     2     0                    0   r[2]=KEY_ID.rowid
9       Rowid          2     3     0                    0   r[3]=KEY_DATA.rowid
10      Ne             3     27    2                    83  if r[2]!=r[3] goto 27
11      Rowid          1     4     0                    0   r[4]=KEY_ID.rowid
12      SeekRowid      3     27    4                    0   intkey=r[4]
13      Rowid          1     3     0                    0   r[3]=KEY_ID.rowid
14      Rowid          3     2     0                    0   r[2]=KEY_PROT.rowid
15      Ne             2     27    3                    83  if r[3]!=r[2] goto 27
16      Column         2     2     5                    0   r[5]=KEY_DATA.CREATOR_ID
17      SeekRowid      4     27    5                    0   intkey=r[5]
18      Column         1     1     6                    0   r[6]=KEY_ID.NAME
19      Column         2     1     7                    0   r[7]=KEY_DATA.KEY_DATA
20      Column         4     1     8                    0   r[8]=CREATORS.NAME
21      Column         2     3     9                    0   r[9]=KEY_DATA.CREATED
22      Column         2     4     10                   0   r[10]=KEY_DATA.MODIFIED
23      Column         2     5     11                   0   r[11]=KEY_DATA.LOCKED
24      Column         3     1     12                   0   r[12]=KEY_PROT.DK_DATA
25      Column         3     2     13                   0   r[13]=KEY_PROT.KEK_DATA
26      ResultRow      6     8     0                    0   output=r[6..13]
27    Next           1     6     0                    1
28    Halt           0     0     0                    0
29    Transaction    0     0     5     0              1   usesStmtJournal=0
30    Goto           0     1     0                    0
```

(I'm tempted to ask: *Who can explain the output of `explain`?*)

All together in a new example:

```sqlite
sqlite> .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE KEY_ID (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(32));
INSERT INTO KEY_ID VALUES(1,'Name1');
INSERT INTO KEY_ID VALUES(2,'Name2');
INSERT INTO KEY_ID VALUES(3,'Name3');
CREATE TABLE CREATORS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(32));
INSERT INTO CREATORS VALUES(1,'Creator1');
INSERT INTO CREATORS VALUES(3,'Creator3');
CREATE TABLE KEY_DATA (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL REFERENCES KEY_ID(ID), KEY_DATA VARCHAR(4096), CREATOR_ID INTEGER not NULL REFERENCES CREATORS(ID), CREATED DATETIME, MODIFIED DATETIME, LOCKED DATETIME);
INSERT INTO KEY_DATA VALUES(1,'K1',1,0,0,0);
INSERT INTO KEY_DATA VALUES(2,'K2',3,0,0,0);
INSERT INTO KEY_DATA VALUES(3,'K3',1,0,0,0);
CREATE TABLE KEY_PROT (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL REFERENCES KEY_ID(ID), DK_DATA VARCHAR(128), KEK_DATA VARCHAR(128));
INSERT INTO KEY_PROT VALUES(1,'A','B');
INSERT INTO KEY_PROT VALUES(2,'C','D');
INSERT INTO KEY_PROT VALUES(3,'E','F');
DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence;
INSERT INTO sqlite_sequence VALUES('KEY_ID',3);
INSERT INTO sqlite_sequence VALUES('CREATORS',3);
CREATE VIEW V AS SELECT KEY_ID.NAME, KEY_DATA, CREATORS.NAME AS CREATOR, CREATED, MODIFIED, LOCKED, KEY_PROT.DK_DATA, KEY_PROT.KEK_DATA FROM KEY_ID INNER JOIN KEY_DATA USING (ID) INNER JOIN KEY_PROT USING(ID) JOIN CREATORS ON CREATORS.ID = KEY_DATA.CREATOR_ID;
COMMIT;
.headers on
sqlite> select * from V;
NAME|KEY_DATA|CREATOR|CREATED|MODIFIED|LOCKED|DK_DATA|KEK_DATA
Name1|K1|Creator1|0|0|0|A|B
Name2|K2|Creator3|0|0|0|C|D
Name3|K3|Creator1|0|0|0|E|F
```

Comment: I could need help: When initially the view seemed correct, I'm facing the problem that the view does not show all the rows it should (in a more realistic scenario).